# python code to insert xml tag at a depth based on parent tag attribute value

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm parsing the following XML file

using xml.etree.ElementTree:

```
<main>
    <stream id="1" name="some">
        <inner id="500">
              <sub-inner>
                 <inside> 500 </inside>
              </sub-inner>
        </inner>
    </stream>
    <stream id="2" name="some">
        <inner id="500">
              <sub-inner>
                 <inside> 500 </inside>
              </sub-inner>
        </inner>
    </stream>
</main>
```

How do I insert < outer>200< /outer> element into the < sub-inner> tag where < stream id ="2" one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `Python lxml` package. : because lxml supports to xpath to fire query on xml.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("C:\\abc.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
elem = tree.xpath("//stream[@id='2']//sub-inner")[0]
elem.append( etree.Element("outer") )
elem1 = tree.xpath("//stream[@id='2']//sub-inner//outer")[0]
elem1.text = "200"
```

It will append new element `outer` in `sub-inner` where `stream id="2"`.

Output will be :

```
<main>
    <stream id="1" name="some">
        <inner id="500">
              <sub-inner>
                 <inside> 500 </inside>
              </sub-inner>
        </inner>
    </stream>
    <stream id="2" name="some">
        <inner id="500">
              <sub-inner>
                 <inside> 500 </inside>
                 <outer>200</outer>
              </sub-inner>
        </inner>
    </stream>
</main>
```